# java.lang.NullPointerException : on android.widget.EditText.addTextchangedlistener

Tags: java, android

I am working on android app and put filtration functionality on `Listview`. But I got below **error**:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   componentInfo:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method void
>   android.widget.EditText.addTextchangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)
>   on a Null object Reference

Below is my code.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.shopdetail);
    aq=new AQuery(this);
    value=5;


                GPSTracker  gps = new GPSTracker(Shopdetail.this);
                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                         getdatalatlog(latitude,longitude);                     
                   }else{
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }                       
                    Intent openStartingPoint=getIntent();
                    String city=openStartingPoint.getStringExtra("spinnerText");
                    bindcity(city);

            final EditText inputSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);                      
                    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                            // When user changed the Text
                            //Shopdetail.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
                            //((SimpleAdapter)Shopdetail.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs); 

                          //  ((SimpleAdapter)getListAdapter()).getFilter().filter(cs); 

                            //get the text in the EditText
                                                                                     EditText inputSearch =    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                             String searchString=inputSearch.getText().toString();
                               int textLength=searchString.length();
                               searchResults.clear();

                               for(int i=0;i<mCommentList.size();i++)
                               {
                              String shopName=mCommentList.get(i).get(TAG_TITLE).toString();
                              if(textLength<=shopName.length()){
                              //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                                 if(searchString.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(shopName.trim().substring(0,textLength))){
                                searchResults.add(mCommentList.get(i));

                                getdata();}
                              }
                               }

                               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                int arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                        }
                    });       
    }

        private void getdata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] data = new String[]{TAG_TITLE,TAG_USERNAME ,TAG_CONTACT ,TAG_MESSAGE ,TAG_LATITUDE , TAG_LONGITUDE };

    int[] to= new int[] {R.id.shop_name,R.id.address,R.id.contact,R.id.distance,R.id.latitude,R.id.longitude};

    final   SimpleAdapter  adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,R.layout.single_post, data,to);

     ListView lv = ( ListView ) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Below is my code to firstly bind data.

```java
    private void getdatalatlog(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //value=5;
        String url = "http://192.168.2.4/PHP/webservice/comments.php?latitude='"+latitude+"'&longitude='"+longitude+"'&value='"+value+"'";
        aq.progress(R.id.progressBar1).ajax(url, JSONObject.class, this,"jsonCallback");

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void jsonCallback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {  


        if (json != null) { 


        List<String> city = new ArrayList<String>();
        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            try {

             JSONArray jsonResponse = json.getJSONArray("posts");
                city = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse.toString(),List.class);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);       

                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String content = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                    String lat = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                    String log = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);
                    String cont = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, content);
                    map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    map.put(TAG_LATITUDE, lat);
                    map.put(TAG_LONGITUDE, log);
                    map.put(TAG_CONTACT, cont);
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mCommentList.add(map);

                searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>(mCommentList);
                //HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //map1.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                //sortdata;


                }
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {

                Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Error in parsing JSON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            String[] data = new String[]{TAG_TITLE,TAG_USERNAME ,TAG_CONTACT ,TAG_MESSAGE ,TAG_LATITUDE , TAG_LONGITUDE };

            int[] to= new int[] {R.id.shop_name,R.id.address,R.id.contact,R.id.distance,R.id.latitude,R.id.longitude};

            final   SimpleAdapter  adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,R.layout.single_post, data,to);

             ListView lv = ( ListView ) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
             lv.setAdapter(adapter);




            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                     Bundle b = new Bundle();


                     String name= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_name)).getText().toString()+" , "+((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact)).getText().toString();

                     String lati= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.latitude)).getText().toString();

                     String longi= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.longitude)).getText().toString();

                     b.putString("shop",name);
                     b.putString("lati",lati);
                     b.putString("long",longi);
                    intent.setClass(Shopdetail.this, Mapview.class);
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });     
    } 
}
```

When user type letter on EditText the data is filtered and its bind in listview according to that. Its not working. Please guide me.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Invoking method on Null object reference will always throw java.lang.NullPointerException.**

In your case, logs clearly indicate "Attempt to invoke method addTextchangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher) on a Null object Reference".

In short - inputSearch is null and should be initialized before any method invocations.

Comment: I check it through debugging, when I write single letter it will go into Textchanged method and when string matches with data its also done perfectly. The issue is only on  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();. Please guide me.

Comment: As suggested by @M-D move `EditText inputSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);` before `inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {`. [See code samples](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html)

Answer (score 10):

You forget to initialized `inputSearch`

```
inputSearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
```

**OR** move

```
 EditText inputSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
```

before

```
 inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
```

Comment: when I type anything on EditText its show lots of error on logcat and main error becuase  of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); this line.